# Improve WPF Application Perceived Cold Startup Performance Using Splash Screen

Tags: c#, wpf, startup, splash-screen

My WPF Application startup is slow (Cold startup), and I want to make the application main window appear as soon as the user double-click on the application’s icon.

I read this [Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jgoldb/2007/10/10/improving-wpf-applications-startup-time/) and I want to add a Splash screen to avoid this delay. I added a splash screen to my application (PNG Image) But I have a questions :

How can I add the initialize code to improve startup, Or the splash screen will shown until the application loaded all the required components ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you load the resources that are so time consuming that the `MainWindow` gets delayed so much. If you are already creating those in the `<App.Resouces />` block in XAML then it's tricky.

When they are created as resources for your view model in the `<MainWindow.Resources />` then quite simply create a tool window or similar containing your splash screen and show it within the `Application_Startup` event like:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    // A Splash-Window to overlay until everything is ready.
    public SplashWindow AppLauncher = new SplashWindow(); 

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        AppLauncher.lblText.Content = "Loading data...";
        AppLauncher.Show();
    }
}
```

And when all resources are loaded in the `MainWindow` then on the `Loaded` event hide/dispose the window again.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (App.Current as App).AppLauncher.Close();
    }
}
```